# How to get Current JPanel from Button Click

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

On the event of clicking a button how would I get the JPanel it is in currently?

I know how to make a button and add an actionlistener and do event handling. I don't know how to select the current panel.

Comment: Usually, you add your `MouseListener's` directly on the `JPanel` and therefore you have a reference to the JPanel with `e.getComponent()`. Providing more context would probably help. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is the best way to do that.

Comment: As rightly pointed out by @GuillaumePolet, you can use `getComponent()`, though if you wanted to know the parent with respect to a certain specific component, you can also have a peek at  [**getParent()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent()) method. This might can also prove useful.

Comment: You should be more specific as to your needs. There may be (and frequently is) more than one JPanel in the parent heirarchy for a given component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code from the post above modified to avoid using final variables

```
public void buildUI() {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
panel.add(button);
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("The current panel is " + ((JButton)e.getComponent()).getParent());
    }

});
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseBehavior(JFrame.CLOSE_ON_EXIT);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I get the error "Cannot cast from ActionEvent to JButton"

Comment: I changed to `System.out.println("The current panel is " + ((JButton)e.getSource()).getParent());` and that fixed the cast error for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void buildUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    panel.add(button);
    button.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("The current panel is " + panel);
        }

    });
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

EDIT: Adding example where listener code is not in the same class as GUI code.

```
//PanelPrintingListener.java
public class PanelPrintingListener implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel panel;

    public PanelPrintingListener(JPanel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("The current panel is " + panel);
    }

}

//OtherFoo.java
public void buildUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    panel.add(button);
    button.addActionListener( new PanelPrintingListener(panel) );
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the listener code is in the same class as the GUI code, which is not always the case.

Comment: Added example which should work even if the listener is in a different class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the panel that is currently active (meaning that it is the top one in the stack), then you can use the getComponent() method.

```
    Component active = parentPanel.getComponent(0);
```

Now the "active" object will have the currently active or displayed panel.Note that "parentPanel" is the panel on which the required sub-panels are placed.